# Multi-part loop-condition satisfied when it shouldn't be

Tags: java

The program below exits the while-loop prematurely. If i take out the `||` leaving only one option to get out of the loop then it works fine. However, I but I don't want this; I want there to be multiple conditions to get out of the loop, not just one.

```
public class password
{  
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new password ();  
    }

    public password ()
    {
        String guess = "";

        //while they haven't got the password yet
        while (!guess.equals ("Rain") || !guess.equals ("rain"))
        {
            guess = IBIO.inputString ("Enter the password: ");

            if (!guess.equals ("Rain") || !guess.equals ("rain"))
            {
                System.out.println ("Sorry please try again.");
            }

        }
        //if they are out of the loop, they got the password
        System.out.println ("Correct, please continue");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use bracketless `if` statements, you should at least put the statement close to the `if` statement lest you accidentally enter another statement in between the `if` and the `System.out.println` later on because it's not clearly in brackets. It's generally a good habit to always use brackets with if statements in Java. I don't sometimes, but I make sure it's very clear. Spreading it out makes it even more confusing/unsightly.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `||` to `&&`

```
if (!guess.equals ("Rain") || !guess.equals ("rain"))
```

is `true` if `guess` doesn't equal "Rain" or if `guess` doesn't equal "rain". If `guess` equals "Rain" then it doesn't equal "rain", so the `if` statement evaluates to `true` when you want it to be `false`.

Same goes for your `while` condition.

```
String guess = "rain";
System.out.println(!guess.equals("Rain"));  // Outputs true
System.out.println(!guess.equals("rain"));  // Outputs false
```

So you are `||`ing a `true` and a `false`, the results of which will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is *always true* right now, because both sides cannot possibly be false at the same time. It looks like you want `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or), so that a guess is correct if it's equal to either `"Rain"` or `"rain"`.

The real issue here is probably that you've organized the code in a way that makes it more difficult to think about than you really needed. What you want to do, intuitively, is "loop until the user inputs either `"Rain"` or `"rain"`." Because you've got your loop set up with all the negations, it's hard to read, and therefore hard to code. To make it easier to understand what's going on, I'd use a construction that looks more like the intuitive design:

```
while (true) { // loop "forever"
    guess = IBIO.inputString ("Enter the password: ");
    if (guess.equals("Rain") || guess.equals("rain")) {
        break; // They got the password right; break out of the loop.
    }
    // If we get here, they got the password wrong, so tell them and keep looping.
    System.out.println ("Sorry please try again.");
}
System.out.println ("Correct, please continue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course `||` must be `&&` here,

This is an *error pattern*: **not comparison1 or not comparison2**

```
!guess.equals ("Rain") || !guess.equals ("rain")
```

Either comparison1 or comparison2 is false so the result is always true - loss of information.
So without considering the meaning, it is probably `&&`.